# Yup's notRequired is not working on radio and urls

Tags: javascript, react-bootstrap, react-hook-form, yup, react-bootstrap-form

I am creating a form using `react-bootstrap`, `react-hook-form`, and `yup` for validation.
I have several fields that are not required like `url` and `radio`.

I have used a custom regex instead of `yup`'s `url()` as it is really strict, for example not accepting `google.com` or `www.google.com`.

Also, there are `radio` type fields like `offerInternships`, `offerVisaSponsorships`, `offerRemoteWorking` which I have declared as `notRequired` in `yup`'s schema.

The problem is when I press `submit` button, errors are shown indicating that they must be filled, and I only be able to proceed if I filled them with correct values.

[image]

I am not really sure what could have gone wrong here.

**Edit 1**: I have modified the regex to accept empty strings by adding `|^$` at the end of `re`, and the url now can accept empty strings and act as if it's not required (I am not sure if this actually fixes the problem), but the `radio` type's problem still exists.

```js
import { Container, Row, Col, Button, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";

/**
 * Company's validation schema.
 */
const re =
  /^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?(?!.*(ftp|http|https|www.))[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+((\/)[\w#]+)*(\/\w+\?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+(&[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+)*)?$/gm;
const formSchema = yup.object().shape({
  url: yup.string().matches(re, "Enter a valid URL!").required(),
  name: yup.string().required(),
  location: yup.object().shape({
    country: yup.string().required(),
    state: yup.string().required(),
    city: yup.string().required(),
    address: yup.string().required(),
  }),
  offerInternships: yup.bool().default(false).notRequired(),
  offerRemoteWork: yup.bool().default(false).notRequired(),
  offerVisaSponsorship: yup.bool().default(false).notRequired(),
  socialMedia: yup.object().shape({
    Linkedin: yup.string().matches(re, "Enter a valid URL!").notRequired(),
    GitHub: yup.string().matches(re, "Enter a valid URL!").notRequired(),
  }),
});
const RequestForm = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(formSchema),
    mode: "all",
  });

  /**
   * Handling the submittion of the form
   */
  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    try {
      console.log(errors);
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Container id="RequestForm-UserForm" className="mt-5 outer-border p-5">
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Row id="company-details-row">
            <Col id="company-details-row-input" sm={12} md={9}>
              <Form.Group className="mb-2" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                <Form.Label>Company's name</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="e.g. Microsoft"
                  {...register("name")}
                  isInvalid={!!errors?.name}
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group className="mb-2" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                <Form.Label>Company's website</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="e.g. https://www.microsoft.com"
                  {...register("url")}
                  isInvalid={!!errors.url}
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <h3 className="mb-0">Location</h3>
              <Form.Group className="mb-2" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                <Form.Label>Country</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="e.g. Egypt, United States of America,...etc."
                  {...register("location.country")}
                  isInvalid={!!errors.location?.country}
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group className="mb-2" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                <Form.Label>State/Governorate</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="e.g. Cairo, California, Berlin...etc."
                  {...register("location.state")}
                  isInvalid={!!errors.location?.state}
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group className="mb-2" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="e.g. Maadi, San Francisco,...etc."
                  {...register("location.city")}
                  isInvalid={!!errors.location?.city}
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group className="mb-2" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="e.g. 14th Zaki Sayed St."
                  {...register("location.address")}
                  isInvalid={!!errors.location?.address}
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <h3 className="mt-2 mb-0">Social Media</h3>
              <Form.Group className="mb-2" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                <Form.Label>
                  <i className="icon ion-social-linkedin"></i> Linkedin
                </Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="e.g. https://www.linkedin.com/company/x"
                  {...register("socialMedia.Linkedin")}
                  isInvalid={!!errors.socialMedia?.Linkedin}
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group className="mb-2" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                <Form.Label>
                  <i className="icon ion-social-github"></i> GitHub
                </Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="e.g. https://www.github.com/company"
                  {...register("socialMedia.GitHub")}
                  isInvalid={!!errors.socialMedia?.GitHub}
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <h3 className="mt-2 mb-0">Culture & Environment</h3>
              <div id="offer-Internship" key={"inline-radio-internships"}>
                <Form.Label>Does your company offer internships? </Form.Label>
                <br></br>
                <Form.Check
                  inline
                  label="Yes"
                  value={"true"}
                  {...register("offerInternships", { required: false })}
                  type={"radio"}
                  isInvalid={!!errors.offerInternships}
                />
                <Form.Check
                  inline
                  label="No"
                  value={"false"}
                  {...register("offerInternships", { required: false })}
                  type={"radio"}
                  isInvalid={!!errors.offerInternships}
                />
              </div>
              <div id="offer-VisaSponsorship" key={"inline-radio-visa"}>
                <Form.Label>
                  Does your company offer visa sponsorship? ✈️
                </Form.Label>
                <br></br>
                <Form.Check
                  inline
                  label="Yes"
                  value={"true"}
                  {...register("offerVisaSponsorship", { required: false })}
                  type={"radio"}
                  isInvalid={!!errors.offerVisaSponsorship}
                />
                <Form.Check
                  {...register("offerVisaSponsorship", { required: false })}
                  inline
                  label="No"
                  value={"false"}
                  type={"radio"}
                  isInvalid={!!errors.offerVisaSponsorship}
                />
              </div>
              <div id="offer-remoteWork" key={"inline-radio-remote"}>
                <Form.Label>
                  Does your company offer remote working? ️
                </Form.Label>
                <br></br>
                <Form.Check
                  {...register("offerRemoteWork", { required: false })}
                  inline
                  label="Yes"
                  value={"true"}
                  type={"radio"}
                  isInvalid={!!errors.offerRemoteWork}
                />
                <Form.Check
                  {...register("offerRemoteWork", { required: false })}
                  inline
                  label="No"
                  value={"false"}
                  type={"radio"}
                  isInvalid={!!errors.offerRemoteWork}
                />
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row id="company-submit text-center">
            <Col className={"text-center"} sm={12}>
              <h2 className="fs-1 main-color-1-dark">
                We have reached to the end of the form! 
              </h2>
              <Button variant="success" type="submit" className="rubik-font">
                Submit form
              </Button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
export default RequestForm;
```

Comment: `socialMedia` by example, is expecting an object with 2 optional items. are you sending an empty object ? if not, make the `yup.object()` optional as well.